# Unable to enable/disable checkbox via [selector].attr & .removeattr

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KU29Q/1/

Goal is to be able to enable and disable a checkbox dynamically. I've tried by referencing the class and/OR id of the checkboxes in question and then use .attr("disabled", "disabled") or .removeAttr("disabled")

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="enableDisable"><label for="check2" >Initially Disabled</label>
<input id="check2" type="checkbox"  class="enableDisable"><label for="check2" >Initially Enabled</label>

//attempt to ENABLE checkbox1
$("check").removeAttr('disabled');

//attempt to change state of second checkbox - DISABLE it...
$(".enableDisable").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("#check2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Also have tried playing around with [selector].prop to no avail. Can someone give me a push in the right direction and/or punch me in the face to relieve my agita?

Thanks.

Comment: **1.** you need to include jQuery in your fiddle. **2.** your class applies to both elements, so you were disabling both of them in the middle line, just use unique IDs: http://jsfiddle.net/KU29Q/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You need to include jQuery in your fiddle

**2.** Your class applies to both elements, so when you use it as a selector for disabling, you disable both elements:

```
$(".enableDisable").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

You should just use the (unique) IDs instead and remove the class selector line:

```
$("#check").removeAttr('disabled');
$('#check2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KU29Q/2/

Answer (score 1):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KU29Q/3/)***

1. Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`
2. For targeting ids use `#` (hash)
3. For classes use `.` (dot)

`//attempt to ENABLE checkbox1`

`$("#check").prop('disabled', false);`

`//attempt to change state of second checkbox - DISABLE it...`

`$("#check2").prop("disabled",true);`